# How to send combo.SelectedItem as string to a function

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I have this following function in C++ CLI:

```
void receiveData(String^ data)
{

}
```

From C# I call the function like this:

```
if (e.OriginalSource is ComboBox)
{
  ComboBox combo = e.OriginalSource as ComboBox;
  if (combo.SelectedItem != null)
  {
      receiveData(combo.SelectedItem as string);
  }
}
```

But inside the function the string parameter is always undefined.
What is the correct way to pass the SelectedItem as string to my function ?

Thanks.

Comment: is SelectedItem of a ComboBox a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItem` returns the selected object. If you want the text, use `SelectedItem.ToString()`. But watch out for nulled selected items, this might be better:

```
string selectedText = combo.SelectedItem == null ? string.Empty  : combo.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

If you do not add strings to the items list, you will get `null` when you use the `as` operator on a variable and try to cast it to a type that it isn't.

Comment: it depends. If TextBox of the ComboBox is editable, SelectedText will return selected chars in TextBox.

Comment: its not editable, but I don't have this property: SelectedText